# Can't set Summernote Options in Backpack for Larvel 4.1

Tags: summernote, laravel-backpack

I'm attempting to set the Summernote options in Backpack for Laravel 4.1 but nothing happens when I adjust the options.

These are the variations I've tried and they seem to have no affect.

```
     [               
            'type' => 'summernote',
            'name' => 'description',
            'options' => [['toolbar', ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'italic']]]],
            'wrapper' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-lg-12',
            ],
            'tab' => $general
      ]

      [
            'type' => 'summernote',
            'name' => 'description',
            'options' => [ ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'italic']]],
            'wrapper' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-lg-12',
            ],
            'tab' => $general

      ]

      [
            'type' => 'summernote',
            'name' => 'description',
            'options' => ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'italic']],
            'wrapper' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-lg-12',
            ],
            'tab' => $general
      ]
```

The editor renders, but the editor options remain the same regardless of the options provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error is in the way you provide the options:

```
  'options' => [
'placeholder'=> 'Hello stand alone ui', 
'height'=> 120,
                  'toolbar'=>[

                      ['style', ['style']],
                      ['font', ['bold']], // show only bold button
                      ['color', ['color']],
                      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                      ['table', ['table']],
                      ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                      ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
                  ]
```

for full description of the Summernote see: [summernote.org](https://summernote.org/)